# Создание строк в MySQL

Tags: mysql

Подскажите пожалуйста правильный запрос для создания одинаковых строк, где только одно значение будет отличаться.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Таблица product_attribute

У меня есть список (около 1000 значений) для product_id, все остальные столбцы будут одинаковые.

То что мне нужно создать:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Уточните вопрос. Непонятно, что вы хотите получить в итоге.

Comment: Я хочу получить допустим 1000 строк со значениями product_id разными (из списка), а attribute_id, language_id, text, preset_id будут в них одинаковые. Вопрос, чтобы я не писал длинный запрос, как я должен его составить.

Comment: Что значит одинаковыми? Напишите пример записей, которые есть в таблице и покажите какие строки *должны* быть выбраны, а какие *нет*. Так будет нагляднее.

Comment: Выше картинку вставил

Comment: Мне их создать нужно

Comment: `INSERT INTO  some_table (fld1,fld2,fld3) SELECT some_table2.fld1 + 1, some_table2.fld2, some_table2.fld3 FROM some_table2 WHERE some_table2.fld1 = 1;`

Comment: Не совсем понял про some_table2. У меня ведь только одна таблица.

Comment: Такой код мне не подходит, потому что товаров у меня много.....INSERT INTO product_attribute (product_id, attribute_id, language_id, text, preset_id) VALUES (222, 23, 1, 'текст', 5), (333, 23, 1, 'текст', 5), (444, 23, 1, 'текст', 5), (555, 23, 1, 'текст', 5)

Comment: Или вы имеете в виду что нужно создать таблицу со списком айдишников товаров?

Comment: Если у вас с `product_id` нет никакой закономерности в его составлении, то только вставка данных вручную

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Можно пойти таким путём:

```
CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE products (
    product_id VARCHAR(255)
);

INSERT INTO products(product_id)
VALUES 
('111'),
('222'),
...

INSERT INTO product_attribute(product_id, attribute_id, language_id, ...)
SELECT product_id, 23, 1, ...
FROM products
```